# Doubts regards REST API

Tags: rest, restful-architecture

I have following doubts in Rest API concepts

1. What is the maximum amount of results returned by Rest API? I mean in terms of         memory.
2. Whether the parameter "page-size" is common for All REST API providers? or Will it depends based on provider?(facebook,twitter,jira etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I as know, there isn't a maximum number of results returned from a REST call. You'll be accidentally limited only from the server implementation that could limit the HTTP payload size.

About your second question, no parameter is common for *all* REST API providers.